# Unable to change date format in Excel using PHP

Tags: php, excel

I am writing lots(around 900 rows) of data into a .xls file using `class.writeexcel_worksheet.inc.php` PHP class. All data written into excel is treated as simple text, even date and time stamps.

Now the problem is while filtering for dates in excel, there is no filter on for months or year. Since all cell values are simple text. **Is there any way to  format my cell to date data type while creating excel through PHP code?**

CODE:

```
<?php
    require_once "class.writeexcel_workbookbig.inc.php";
    require_once "class.writeexcel_worksheet.inc.php";
    require_once "db_params.php";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $heure = date("H_i");
    $fname = tempnam("/tmp", $date."_".$heure.".xls");
    $workbook = &new writeexcel_workbookbig($fname);
    $worksheet = &$workbook->addworksheet();
    $mainheading =& $workbook->addformat();
    $mainheading->set_color('white');
    $mainheading->set_pattern(0x1);
    $mainheading->set_align('center');
    $mainheading->set_border_color('black');
    $mainheading->set_border(1);
    $mainheading->set_merge();
    $worksheet->write("A1", "Observation", $mainheading, $border2);
    $worksheet->set_column(0, 50, 18);
    $worksheet->freeze_panes(2, 0); # 1 row
    $worksheet->merge_cells("A1:L1");
    $heading =& $workbook->addformat();
    $heading->set_color('white');
    $heading->set_align('center');
    $heading->set_align('vcenter');
    $worksheet->set_column(0, 50, 18);  
    //$worksheet->set_outline();
    $worksheet->set_margins(2); 
    # Create a border format
    $border1 =& $workbook->addformat();
    $border1->set_color('black');
    $border1->set_pattern(0x1);
    $border1->set_fg_color('white');
    $border1->set_border_color('black');
    $border1->set_border(1);
    $border1->set_text_wrap();
    $col=0;
    $query = "SELECT * from Incidents";
    $res=sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,array(), array('Scrollable'=>SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC));
    $Entete1 = array("Incident ID - Hyperlink to AR" , "Reported Date", "Service", "Priority", "Operational  Categorization Tier 1", "Summary", "Assignment Date", "Status", "Last Assigned Group", "Resolution Status", "Time bef. first assignment", "Number of assignments");
    foreach($Entete1 as $value) {
    $worksheet->write(1, $col, $value,$heading);
    $col++;
    }
    $col=0;
    $Entete11 = array("IncidentID", "ReportDate", "Service", "Priority", "OperationalCategoryT1", "Summary", "AssignmentDate", "Status", "LastAssignedGroup", "ResolutionStatus", "AcknowledgmentTime", "NoOFAssignment", "Team", "Remarks", "RemarkCategory" , "PloneforgeNo" ,"ProdCategorisationT1", "ProdCategorisationT2", "ProdCategorisationT3", "Urgency", "Impact", "Resolved_date", "Category_tier1", "ResolutionDetails", "Name", "LastResolvedDate", "Resolution", "OLAStatus", "OLAUpTime", "ReopenedDate", "StatusReason", "BucketDate", "OLAProgress", "DueDateTime", "GoalTime");
    foreach($Entete11 as $value) 
    {
        $x=2;
        $y=2;
        for( $position = SQLSRV_SCROLL_FIRST ; ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH, $position)) ; $position = SQLSRV_SCROLL_NEXT )
        {   

            $chaine = strip_tags($row[$value]);

                $worksheet->write($x, $col, $chaine, $border1);
                $x++;   
        }
        $col++;

    }
    $workbook->close();
    header("Content-Type: application/x-msexcel; name=".$date."_".$heure.".xls");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$date."_".$heure.".xls");
    $fh=fopen($fname, "rb");
    fpassthru($fh);
    unlink($fname);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please put fragment of your code inside the question?

Comment: This looks like PHP/4 code. Is it a third-party library or some in-house product?

Comment: Yes this is a third party library used for writing into excel and creates a .xls file.

Comment: Then it all depends on whether that library (whichever it is) is good enough to let you choose the cell data format. That should be explained in the documentation (or source code if there aren't docs available). Sorry, there's not much else we can say.

Comment: I have successfully converted my date(text type) using DATE function of excel to date type. Now the problem i am facing is its giving me some random value like 42195.
The formula i applied in my php code is '=DATE(MID(G15,7,4),MID(G15,1,2),MID(G15,4,2))'.
I have to now make my cell date type. Please help it is urgently required in my project